# How can I tell if my gas fire is fitted correctly?

Tags: gas, fireplace

In a correctly fitted gas fire should the ignition system be so visible, and the base so high?

How could I find if this is a correct fitting for this fire, or if not how it should have been fitted?

This is a new installation, a new gas fire supplied with a new fireplace.

[image: Gas fire]

Answer (score 1):

Um, wow. Rule #1 of home improvement: If it doesn't look right, it probably isn't. Looks like you can see the manufacturer's tag there behind the bar with the ignition. I'd contact them and see what they say; they're the only ones who can say for sure.

Comment: A good thought. I've sent them the picture, see if they comment

Comment: No reply from Maxi, the manufacturers. Not even an acknowledgement.